# XML::twig to copy node tree from one file to another

Tags: xml, perl, perl-module, xml-twig

I have two huge XML files (>50M), and would like to append a node tree from one XML to another.

test1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<blocks>
    <block name="block1" id="1">
        <lotsofcontents/>
    </block>
    <block name="block3" id="3">
            <lotsofcontents />
    </block>
</blocks>
</root>
```

test2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<blocks>
    <block name="block2" id="2">
        <lotsofcontents/>
    </block>
    <block name="block4" id="4">
            <lotsofcontents />
    </block>
</blocks>
</root>
```

I would like to copy all the blocks from test2.xml to test1.xml, so the result looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<blocks>
    <block name="block1" id="1">
        <lotsofcontents/>
    </block>
    <block name="block3" id="3">
        <lotsofcontents/>
    </block>
    <block name="block2" id="2">
        <lotsofcontents/>
    </block>
    <block name="block4" id="4">
        <lotsofcontents/>
    </block>
</blocks>
</root>
```

I tried with XML Twig code as below:

combine.pl

```
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $testa = "test1.xml";
my $testb = "test2.xml";
my $result = "result.xml";
my $MDTAG = "block";

my @blocks;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => {
                                            $MDTAG => sub {push @blocks; $_->cut_children; },
                                        },
                       pretty_print => 'indented',
                       empty_tags => 'expand',
                     );
$twig->parsefile($testb);

my $phere = XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => {
                                            $MDTAG => sub { foreach my $block (@blocks)
                                                    { $block->paste( first_child => $_); } },
                                         },
                       pretty_print => 'indented',
                     );
$phere->parsefile($testa);
$phere->print_to_file($result);
```

I am getting warning as below and result.xml gets generated but nothing from test2.xml gets appended.

```
Useless use of push with no values at combine.pl line 16.
Use of tied on a handle without * is deprecated at /opt/perl/lib/XML/Parser/Expat.pm line 447.
Use of tied on a handle without * is deprecated at /opt/perl/lib/XML/Parser/Expat.pm line 447.
```

Appreciate for any correction and comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think, for the main document you need to set up a handler for the `blocks` element, not for each `block` element.

With

```
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $testa = "test2015122401.xml";
my $testb = "test2015122402.xml";
my $result = "result2015122401.xml";

my @blocks;

my $t1= XML::Twig->new(  
         twig_handlers   => { 'block' => sub { push @blocks, $_; $_->cut(); }}
                    );
$t1->parsefile( $testb);


my $phere = XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => {
                                            '/root/blocks' => sub { 
                                               foreach my $block (@blocks) {
                                                 $block->paste(last_child => $_);
                                               }
                                             }
                                         },
                       pretty_print => 'indented',
                     );
$phere->parsefile($testa);
$phere->print_to_file($result);
```

I get the result you want for the samples you posted.